# WIN 8.1 iso download corrupt

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Hello i got a genuine win8 key.I am using this method mentioned here to get the win8.1 iso file.
http://philipyip.wordpress.com/download-microsoft-windows/download-windows-8-1-iso/

Win 8.1 iso is downloading just fine.But after download when it checking the file its getting stuck at 19% and giving me error download is corrupt.This happened twice in a row now.It always gets stuck at 19% and gives me error corrupt download,.Then it starts downlaoding again.How can i fix this?

Comment: I followed the directions and was given an .iso file that was complete.